# How I can write template, what can’t be any type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

As example, let’s write function min

```
template <typename T>
T min(T a, T b) {
  return (a < b)? a: b;
}
```

I want it to work with `char`, `int`, `long`, `uint*_t`, `int*_t`, `MyIntegerType`, etc. But I don’t want it work with `std::string`, `char *`, `MyClass`, etc. What should I do?

Comment: [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) can check for any built-in integral types. What is `MyIntegerType`?

Comment: What is the difference between `MyIntegerType` and `MyClass`?

Comment: You can delete the ones you want to forbid, `template <> std::string min<std::string>(std::string, std::string) = delete;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `std::integral` concept to constrain the template to integral types

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral T>
T min(T a, T b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Then create overloads for every class type that you want to support

```cpp
MyIntegerType min(MyIntegerType a, MyIntegerType b) {
    // ...
}
```

Make sure you compile in C++20 mode to use concepts. To constrain templates before C++20 you can use SFINAE, but it is much harder to write and to read than concepts:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type min(T a, T b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```